# How to change the language of GlassFish Admin Console?

Tags: configuration, glassfish, settings, glassfish-4

My GlassFish UI Language is not in English, how to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is set based on your browsers locale preferences, so you only need to change them and reload the page.

In Firefox you can do this under `Preferences` - `Content` - `Languages`

In Chrome/Chromium just search for "language" in the preferences search.

If changing the preferred browser locale is not an option for you, you can also download the english only version of Glassfish.